# C++ Load Document Error. Trying to test

Tags: c++, file, input, output

I'm working on a project from class and it's a text analysis project. We're supposed to load a document into the program and basically read data from it. Ex: (word count, sentence count, etc.). For some reason, my first function isn't working correctly: my `loadDocument` function is supposed to load the document into the program.

Here is the code in main to call that function:

```
case 1: // Load Document
{
    string inputLoc;
    cout << "Please input the document name:" << endl;
    cin >> docName;
    myDocs[docCount].setName(docName);
    myDocs[docCount].id = docCount;
    cout << "Input Location: " << endl;
    cin >> inputLoc;
    myDocs[docCount].loadDocument(inputLoc);
    docCount++;
    break;
}
```

I have `docName` initialized outside of the case - before it.

Here is my `loadDocument` in side my `Document` class:

```
void Document::loadDocument(string name)
{
    ifstream myFile(name);
    int numOflines = 0;
    string theLine;
    char words;

    while (myFile.get(words))
    {
        switch (words)
        {
        case '.':
            numOflines++;
            break;
        case '?':
            numOflines++;
            break;
        case '!':
            numOflines++;
            break;
        }
    }

    lineCount = numOflines;
    setLineCt(numOflines);
    arr = new Line[lineCount];
    myFile.close();
    char theChar;
    ifstream myFile2(name);
    int key = 0;

    if (myFile2.is_open())
    {
        for (id = 0; id < lineCount; id++)
        {
            while (theChar != '.' || theChar != '!' || theChar != '?')
            {
                myFile2 >> noskipws >> theChar;
                theLine[key] = theChar;
                key++;
            }

            myFile2 >> theChar;

            arr[id].setStr(theLine);
        }
    }
}
```

I just wanted to know if my `loadDocument` has any evident bugs? For some reason, it's not actually loading a document into the program. For the input location, I typed in the exact file location of a text file that I want to input. For ex: `C:\Users\Documents------`. After I input that, my program just goes into an infinite loop.

Is my `loadDocument` doing what it's supposed to do? It's supposed to open a document and extract the number of sentences from it as well as number of words.

Also, am I testing it correctly by typing in that file location like that?  I'm new to file input/output sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while()` loop is incorrect:

```
while (theChar != '.' || theChar != '!' || theChar != '?')
```

`||` is not the right conditional operator here. If one condition is false, the two others will be true, thus leading to the infinite loop. You have to use `&&`:

```
while (theChar != '.' && theChar != '!' && theChar != '?')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I changed that and realize why I was wrong. Thanks. But some reason it's still going in the infinite loop in my menu. Am I testing it correctly?

Comment: @user3421510 I think the other problem is that you're not checking if your input succeeded before executing the `while()` loop. Take the first line from the loop and add it as a condition, like this: `while (myFile2 >> noskipws >> theChar && theChar != '.' && theChar != '!' && theChar != '?')`

Comment: Then I have to delete that myFile2>>noskipws>>theChar from within the loop right?

Comment: @user3421510 Correct.

Comment: Oh sorry. For some reason, it's still going into the infinite loop in main. But it's only for case 1. There must be something in that case 1 that is going wrong. I just can't figure out what